# Swagger api listing is empty

Tags: api, rest, jersey, jax-rs, swagger

Recently I have configure swagger with one of my project. Its using jersey2 and JAX-WS on tomcat for restful API. I have used following manual to configure

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5

${basepath}/swagger.json response with following

> {"swagger":"2.0","info":{"version":"1.0.0","title":""},"host":"localhost:8080","basePath":"/myapi","schemes":["http"]}

Unfortounately it does not contain any api which is under my resource package.
I have tried with the answer of following question

[swagger - empty listing with no API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240720/swagger-empty-listing-with-no-api)

But it didn't help either.
The above answer using com.wordnik.swagger.* package(s)
But with the manual I got io.swagger.* package(s), which doesn't have 
JaxrsApiReader class

My assumption is swagger couldn't scan my api list from Resource package.
But could not figure out which configuration or which code snippet I have missed.

Any help?....

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you forgot to mark the rest endpoints with `@Api`

Comment: Where's the swagger documentation on this. I'm unable to find it.

Comment: The annotation docs are here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I used a different approach that worked for me, by adding information only in my Application class. In case you have one, that might help you:

```
public class MyApi extends Application {

    public MyApi() {
        super();
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setTitle("MyApi");
        beanConfig.setVersion("0.0.1");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http", "https"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/mypath");

        //putting only the path to my api unblocked me, I removed "io.swagger.resources"
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("system.organization.api"); 
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
        beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<>();

        s.add(MyApis);

        //for swagger
        s.add(ApiListingResource.class);
        s.add(SwaggerSerializers.class);

        return s;
    }
}
```

Then, the links of classes with @API annotation appeared in swagger.json

Mostly done with the same manual you used: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-1.X-Project-Setup-1.5

Comment: I only need put @Api on Services. I do not need override getClasses(). In web.xml I add: <context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>

Comment: Removing the "io.swagger.resources" from resource pakages works for me.